# Can't install modules 'os' and 'os.path'

Tags: python, python-3.x, redhat

I am trying to install 'os' module and 'os.path' module on a red hat machine. I tries following commands.

```
pip install os
yum install os
```

But I keep gettin the following error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement os.path (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for os.path
```

I am able to install other modules using aforementioned command but not able to install these.

I need to install both os and os.path.

Using version python 3.4.3

Comment: Those are both standard/core modules that are present in every Python installation (I believe `os` is actually built into the interpreter).  What makes you think you need to install them/that they aren't already installed?

Comment: You don't ahve to install them as jwodder said

Answer (score 9):

Take a look into this extensive list of [Python Library 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/index.html). If it's mentioned there that means it's already included in the original installation of Python. More specifically [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html)

The reason you're getting this specific error because you're trying to install something that doesn't exist. The hint for that is *os.path (from versions: )* meaning there isn't an external package that matches "os.path" or any proper version of it.

Comment: I was trying to figure out why I was getting error message when building workflow, this solved it, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this command. It worked in my system.

```
pip install path.py
```